# assigning a range of values to a single variable

Tags: java, variables

I have initialized a double variable called vatValue and I am supposed to assign value which ranges between 0.00 to 99.99.

//initalize vatValue to a value between 0.00 and 99.99.

Is it possible to assign them both together?

Comment: Primitive variables can't contain value ranges, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Not Possible to assign two values to primitive variable

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign multiple values to a variable, but the comment you posted sounds like it needs one value between 0.00 and 99.99. What are you trying to accomplish with this problem? Does the value need to be random?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. depending on your requirements you might want to create a class that has two 'double' properties